# How to randomize wood pattern in many object?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I want to make wood house. but my wood pattern is not nature. If i use texture, all woods have same pattern. Is there any way to randomize wood pattern?

Comment: Is your wood image-based, or procedural?

Comment: That is image-based

Answer (score 1):

so you can use object info node for this!

just add a mix rgb node and put the image texture in the first node and a color ramp in the second one. just choose some shades of grey in the ramp. you might want to choose similar types of shades. just vary them a little( my colors are too drastic).[image]

no each copy of the wood mesh will have different color due to the mixing. rememder to make the wood meshes different objects(duplicate them in object mode not in edit mode).

[image]

Now to vary the wooden pattern, yoou can scale he uvs differently and get different patterns, just move the uvs randomly and scale them a litle. remember to use UV coordinates in your image texture.[image]

you can combine both methods to get different looking wood materials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is helpful tip for me. but i want to know not only randomizing the color but also randomizing wood pattern. If you know that way, please give me a tip. Because I am not fluent in English, i'm sorry to you about my rudeness not intended

Comment: ok i have edited the comment